# Как поменять стили для элементов в таблицах DataTable в jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatable

Как в jquery в DataTable изменять стили и центрирование каких-либо элементов?
Например, мне нужно уменьшить шрифт текста и размер окна выпадашки вот этого меню и отцентрировать его по правому краю [image: Меню переместить вправо и изменить шрифт]

На нашел нужных опций в FAQ по этим таблицам, которые отвечают за стилизацию. То есть, язык поменять, заменить текст и прочее нетрудно, а вот изменить стили не понимаю как.

Answer (score -1):

Изменять стили в файле css.
Если например ты на бутстрапе делаешь, то изменяешь свойства классов таблицы `datatables`.

А позиции вот есть свойства для `datatables`
https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom